# Heroku - Node version not specified in package.json while deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I was deploying my React app to Heroku but was getting this error while deploying.
When i run the code locally it's running fine.
This is the Heroku build log for refrence.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.18.2...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.15
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! bindings not accessible from watchpack-chokidar2:fsevents
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.4mm12/_logs/2022-01-09T12_08_27_820Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
 !     Push failed
```

I checked package.json but didnt found any mistake
This is a part of Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "node": "16.x",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-github-calendar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-parallax-tilt": "^1.4.68",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.4.1",
    "react-pdf": "^5.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.17.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  }
}
```

Please let me know where is the problem here

Comment: error is mentioned  ```npm ERR! bindings not accessible from watchpack-chokidar2```

Comment: remove packages-lock.json and running again using NodeJS 14

Comment: Note: Git has nothing to do with this. While you use Git to send the commits around so that Heroku can operate on them, Git is merely a transport system in this setup. It relays the commit to Heroku, then relays Heroku's errors back to you. It has nothing to do *with* those errors, nor about them.

Answer (score 5):

You should precise which version of node you want to use to run your app and add the following to your package.json:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.5"
  }
```

Adapt the value to your need.

Answer (score 0):

remove packages-lock.json and run again the node js app